# Multi step form button disable until form select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This is my form it a multi step form, when I filed a step, then button is enable and going to the next step, until the form field button has been disabled. I want to select-item select button has disabled. How can I do that?

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="ccSelectForm">

    <select name="select-item" class="form-control" id="select_field">
            <option value="">Select your option</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-continue">
        <button type="button" id="register2" class="btn btn-default next-step ">Continue</button>       
    </div>


     <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="tab-form-content">
            <h2>What are your <b>overall goals?</b></h2>
            <div class="bor-bottom"></div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone number">
                </div>

                <div class="btn-continue">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-default next-step register">Submit</button>

                    <br />

                    <button type="button" id="register3" class="btn go-back prev-step">Go Back</button>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</form>



 $(document).ready(function () {
      $( "#register2,#register3" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $('#ccSelectForm').validate({
            rules: {
                website: {
                    required: true, 
                },
                optionsRadios: {
                    required: true, 
                },
                budget: {
                    required: true, 
                },
                name: {
                    required: true,
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                },
                phone_number: {
                    required: true,
                }
               /*  inputEmailConfirm: {
                    equalTo: '#inputEmail'
                } */
            }
        });

        $('#ccSelectForm input').on('keyup blur', function () {
            if ($('#ccSelectForm').valid()) {
                $( "#register2,#register3").prop( "disabled", false );
            } else {
                  $( "#register2,#register3" ).prop( "disabled", true );
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a Disabled button

`<button type="button" id="register2" class="btn btn-default next-step " disabled="disabled">Continue</button>`

Put a function on your select change if item selected enable the button

```
$(function(){
    $('#select_field').change(function(){
        var itemVal = $(this).val();
        if(itemVal != ''){
            $('#register2').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else{
            $('#register2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```